# Best way to get instance-id using clojure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, clojure

I'm using the clojure client [amazonica](https://github.com/mcohen01/amazonica) for trying out clojure and write some scripts to help with managing aws ec2 instances.

I'm trying to get the instance-id using this snippet:

```
(def instances ((describe-instances) :reservations))
(def an_instance ((first instances) :instances))
(def instance_id ((first an_instance) :instance-id))
```

Looking for a way to do this better, so I can use it for any other json output.

EDIT: trying to get the instance-id, security groups and tag names from an instance.

In addition to the above question, when I use the amazonica client which uses the aws java sdk version 1.9.33, I get this on the console:

```
May 10, 2015 1:31:57 PM com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient logRequestId
INFO: x-amzn-RequestId: not available
```

What can I do to fix that?

EDIT: To clarify, I'm trying to this info from outside the VPC or the instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find the instance-id from the instance itself:

```
(slurp "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id")
```

(See [Instance Metadata and User Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) for more information.)

To find selected properties for all your instances:

```
(map #(select-keys % [:instance-id :tags :security-groups])
     (flatten
      (map :instances
           (:reservations
            (amazonica.aws.ec2/describe-instances)))))
```

Comment: And in cases where I am not calling that from within the instance itself?

Comment: What information do you have about the instance for which you want to find the instance ID?

Comment: only my aws access key and secret. want to get information about instances - specifically their instance-ids, tag names and security groups.

Comment: Added to the answer - please clarify in your question.